How to make login page of oAuth inspectable with iOS 17 as it is opening in app browser window for our app using angular
I want to inspect/debug in Safari when I am at the login page of oauth that is opening in the app browser window.
I am not able to find a way to debug the login page of oAuth with an ios 17.5 app.
Even with ios 17.5, I am not able to inspect the ios app, but my team did some custom configuration to work with that.
Now, I want to inspect the Oauth login page.
The version I am using: "angular-oauth2-oidc": "^15.0.1"
I am expecting a configuration that would help me inspecting my oauth login page with safari when I debug.

Are you using electron.js for your app?

No, in our project we are using cordova ionic typescript.
